# Вызов лямбды из очереди

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Потребовалось вызывать лямбду по сигналу, но не напрямую, а из очереди событий. Пытаюсь подключить:

```
connect(model, &MyModel::modelReset, [this]() {}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Компилятор начинает ругаться. Как победить без необходимости создания полноценного метода в классе?

**Дополнение**

Ругается на отсутствие подходящего метода для `connect()`:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'MyClass::connect(MyModel*&, void
>   (QAbstractItemModel::*)(QAbstractItemModel::QPrivateSignal),
>   MyClass::myMethod()::, Qt::ConnectionType)'
>        connect(model, &MyModel::modelReset, this {}, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: А на что ругается, можете привести вывод компилятора?

Comment: И вроде бы `Qt::ConnectionType` работает, только если используется наследник QObject.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian , обновил ответ. У меня класс `MyClass` - наследник `QAbstractItemModel` и соответственно `QObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если хотите использовать лямбду и очередь событий, то нужно указать, в каком *контексте* эта очередь существует. У Вас недостаёт аргумента в вызове, должно быть так:

```
connect(model, &MyModel::modelReset, context, [this]() {}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Где `context` это наследник `QObject`(всё точно так же, как и в случае со старым синтаксисом `connect`)

Comment: Чтоб меня, спасибо большое, очень выручили. У троллей на форуме написано, что, мол, нифига так [нельзя](https://forum.qt.io/topic/29179/solved-qt5-can-t-define-connection-type-for-functions-and-functors/2), а оказывается можно.

Comment: @alexis031182, там модератор просто не разобрался в вопросе, в документации ведь описан как раз такой случай. Да и по логике вещей, такой вызов должен быть возможен; в подобной потребности нет ничего экстраординарного, это типичное использование.

Comment: Да вот я тоже подумал, что должно быть возможно (ранее просто не возникала потребность в сабжекте), но у самого не завелось, начал искать ответ, а у троллей - печаль. Спасибо ещё раз.